# Converting Hexidecimal Strings to Numeric Types and back

Tags: c#, hex, byte, int32

I need a function to convert hex values in the format `0xFFFF` (2 Bytes) to decimal (unsigned and signed).

For example:

`0xFFFE` is `65534`  (unsigned)
`0xFFFE` is `-2`     (signed)

I need also the same thing for **4 Bytes and 1 Byte**.

All these options (3 * 2 options) I need to convert back - from decimal to hex (total 12 options).

My function should look like this:

```
    string Myconverter(int ByteSize, bool IsFromHextoDecimal, bool IsSigned)
    {
        ...
    }
```

If there's build in functionality that performs these conversions, I'd like to a reference/link.

Comment: Have a look at [How to: Convert Between Hexadecimal Strings and Numeric Types (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311038.aspx) (courtesy of MSDN)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use methods in the `Convert` class to parse the string to a number. To parse an unsigned 2 byte value you use the `ToUInt16` method, and specify the base 16:

```
ushort value = Convert.ToUInt16("0xFFFF", 16);
```

Use these methods for other format:

```
ToInt16  = signed 2 byte
ToUInt32 = unsigned 4 byte
ToInt32  = signed 4 byte
ToByte   = unsigned 1 byte
ToSByte  = signed 1 byte
```

To format a number to a hexadecimal string you can use the `X` format (or `x` to get lower case letters) and specify the number of digits:

```
string formatted = value.ToString("X4");
```

That will however not have the `0x` prefix, so if you want that you have to add it:

```
string formatted = "0x" + value.ToString("X4");
```